# Angular2 web pack proxy configuration

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server

Since angular-cli is maturing nicely, I decided to port an Angular2 app to take advantage of angular-cli awesomeness. However proxying to an external remote service running on localhost is taking on a wild trip.

Version Info

```
ng --version
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3
node: 7.0.0
os: darwin x64
```

So from angular app, I would like to proxy all `/service/**` requests to a RESTful api running on nginx @ `http://localhost.api.co.za`

*Configurations*

```
{
  "/service/*" : {
    "target":"http://localhost.api.co.za/",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
    "^/service": ""
    }
  }
}
```

nginx access.log prints out a **404** `POST /api/v1/testing HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "http://localhost:4200/contact"`

Tried all the tricks in this port [webpack-dev-server proxy dosen't work](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/458)

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy

Answer (score 0):

After multiple adjustments and trolling through web pack documentation along with [http-proxy-middleware docs on github](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware)

Configurations that worked for my case where:

```
{
  "/service" : {
    "target":"http://localhost.api.co.za",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```